How to convert font from 1980s that is now in .dfont to OTF or TTF?
Context: I'm working on my personal website and want to use the classical Toronto font from the 1980s. I found this .dfont version in an old repo.
Problem: I need a modern format I can use for Figma and the web. For example, OTF or TTF.
What I tried?: Countless online converters and FontForge, which throws out the warning of “no glyphs” when converting.
If somebody find an archived version in a more suitable format, that would be an even better solution. I unfortunately couldn't.

You sure you need to? Just looking at the dFont.. looks like Helvetica with really bad spacing, unless the preview in wrong. this might work.. https://www.vertopal.com/en/convert/fon-to-dfont

There's a truetype version of Toronto here - they've renamed it Torrance.

@BillyKerr Thanks. I already tried this one, but it unfortunately looks substantially different. It's super curvy, while the other has a 8bit-look (in layman terms).

@Scott thanks, but then the preview is wrong. Here's a visual.
I also already tried the converter you mentioned, and it unfortunately doesn't work in this case.

Yes. I see with your preview that the converter was.. well, junk. Sorry. I wonder if downloading old Mac Systems would have it. I tried System 7, but the disk images are too old to be even open or convert here (using a legacy OSX version still having the carbon libraries). Unfortunately, I'm not certain this is as much a "design" question as a "find it for me" question.

The dfont files just contain bitmap data - no contours and lines at all. FontForge will open it, but FontLab won't touch it. I'd be surprised if there isn't a similar bitmap-effect font out there somewhere that you could use instead. Weirdly, .dfonts weren't used until the OS X changeover.
